# Reloading control

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I have created a custom control which I am using multiple times on the page.
I checked value at the Loaded event.

Due to long delay of data retrieval, I am not able to check value at the control loaded event.

Now I need to reload the control after data retrieval from the WCF service.

Can you please suggest me the right approach to do the same.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Silverlight to call a WCF service to get your data, you will be working Asynchronous right?

You could hook up the completed event of your webservice call to do anything (like reloading, rebinding your controls) you want after the data has been retrieved from your WCF service.

It would be better if you could set up binding to your custom control. Whenever the observable data is retrieved and assigned to your binding object, your control will be updated.